# Expandable Floating Action Button doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm trying to use the Expandable Floating Action Button available at the link: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/expandable-fab but the internal buttons don't work, I press them and nothing happens. I'm using this widget inside a Stack. Below the Expandable Floating Action Button code is where it is used;

```
@immutable
class ExpandableFab extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool? initialOpen;
  final double distance;
  final List<Widget> children;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  const ExpandableFab({
    super.key,
    this.initialOpen,
    required this.distance,
    required this.children,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  _ExpandableFabState createState() => _ExpandableFabState();
}

class _ExpandableFabState extends State<ExpandableFab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  late final Animation<double> _expandAnimation;
  bool _open = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _open = widget.initialOpen ?? false;
    _controller = AnimationController(
      value: _open ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _expandAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      reverseCurve: Curves.easeOutQuad,
      parent: _controller,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _open = !_open;
      if (_open) {
        _controller.forward();
      } else {
        _controller.reverse();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          _buildTapToCloseFab(),
          ..._buildExpandingActionButtons(),
          _buildTapToOpenFab()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTapToCloseFab() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 56.0,
      height: 56.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Material(
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: _toggle,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.deepPurple),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildExpandingActionButtons() {
    final children = <Widget>[];
    final count = widget.children.length;
    final step = 90.0 / (count - 1);
    for (var i = 0, angleInDegrees = 0.0;
        i < count;
        i++, angleInDegrees += step) {
      children.add(
        _ExpandingActionButton(
          directionInDegrees: angleInDegrees,
          maxDistance: widget.distance,
          progress: _expandAnimation,
          child: widget.children[i],
        ),
      );
    }
    return children;
  }

  Widget _buildTapToOpenFab() {
    return IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: _open,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(
          _open ? 0.7 : 1.0,
          _open ? 0.7 : 1.0,
          1.0,
        ),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeOut),
        child: AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: _open ? 0.0 : 1.0,
          curve: const Interval(0.25, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.deepPurple, // Button color
              child: InkWell(
                //splashColor: Colors.white, // Splash color
                onLongPress: _toggle,
                onTap: widget.onTap,
                onDoubleTap: () {},
                child: const SizedBox(
                  width: 56,
                  height: 56,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class _ExpandingActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ExpandingActionButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.directionInDegrees,
    required this.maxDistance,
    required this.progress,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double directionInDegrees;
  final double maxDistance;
  final Animation<double> progress;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: progress,
      builder: (context, child) {
        final offset = Offset.fromDirection(
          directionInDegrees * (math.pi / 180.0),
          progress.value * maxDistance,
        );
        return Positioned(
          right: 4.0 + offset.dx,
          bottom: 4.0 + offset.dy,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: (1.0 - progress.value) * math.pi / 2,
            child: child!,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: FadeTransition(opacity: progress, child: child),
    );
  }
}

@immutable
class ActionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ActionButton({
    super.key,
    this.onPressed,
    required this.icon,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final Widget icon;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Material(
      shape: const CircleBorder(),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
      elevation: 4.0,
      child: IconTheme.merge(
        data: theme.primaryIconTheme,
        child: IconButton(onPressed: onPressed, icon: icon),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Expandable FLoating Action Button is used within this Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // some widget
    Positioned(
      right: 30.0,
      bottom: 140.0,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        child: ExpandableFab(
          distance: 112.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test1");
              },
            ),
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test2");
              },
            ),
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test3");
              },
            )
          ],
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint("test4");
          },
        ),
      ),
    ), 
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use it in the stack, place the code for the ExpandedButton in the last position so that it gets reported with touch events.

Code sample:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // All your other widgets go up here
    RandomWidget(),
    RandomWidget2(),
    ........... //other widgets

    // This comes last.
    Positioned(
      right: 30.0,
      bottom: 140.0,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 60.0,
        height: 60.0,
        child: ExpandableFab(
          distance: 112.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test1");
              },
            ),
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test2");
              },
            ),
            ActionButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("test3");
              },
            )
          ],
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint("test4");
          },
        ),
      ),
    ), 
  ],
),
```

By the way, Why are you using this in a stack? You can pretty much use it as a `FloatingActionButton` by passing it to `floatingActionButton` parameter of the `Scaffold`.